# Trapping MouseOver, of an object in PowerPoint

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

Can I trap the mouseover somehow, of an object in PowerPoint.

In my PowerPoint addin, I want to be able to know when the mouse is over which object. The objects are not activex, they are built-in standard objects (pictures, etc...) for any powerpoint.

I need to do this in design mode, of the presentation, not in run/presentation mode.

Comment: What is the end result you are looking for?  Maybe there is some other way to do it

Comment: I want my GUI to come up, next to the object, when I hover over it. My tool modifies them. I already have it working on double click but I wanted the small GUI to automatically appear when I select it or highlight it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but [here](http://www.pptworkbench.com/html/mouse_over_images.htm) is an article showing how to start animations using a mouseover

Comment: This is awesome, thanks... but I failed to write that I needed it in design mode, not run (f5) mode.